# Firefox won't remember my download settings

Tags: firefox

Firefox 22 on Windows 7 Pro 32 bits. It's not remembering my download handling settings when I check the "remember decision for this file type" (or something like that) checkmark box. I have disabled every extension, but the issue persists.

My goal is to have every .exe, .zip, .rar, etc that I click to be handled by DownThemAll, as if I had chosen "dTa OneClick" and then clicked "OK", but with two clicks less.

Is that even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> General -> Options -> Downloads, and choose the action to be taken when a download is prompted.

Comment: There's no "Tools -> General -> Options -> Downloads" section for me. By default there's no menu bar on FF 22 for windows, if I click on the dropdown menu I get "options", then "options" again as a subchoice for it. In both cases there's a "general" tab, but there's not another "option" choice under it. Can you please provide a screenshot?